# How to split list

Tags: java, list

I've got an ArrayList which is filled from input file line by line.
One line is one index here, so I need to split that by words because I dont want that.
Can someone explain me how to do that? I prefer to use Lists not Arrays btw.

```
    Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("C:\\X\\X.txt"));
    Scanner data2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Y\\Y.txt"));

    List<String> file1 = new ArrayList<>(write1(data));
    List<String> file2 = new ArrayList<>(write2(data2));
```

**Actual output is:**

```
[Ian Kowalsky 2000, Pit Johnson 2001, Adam Todd 1999]
```

**Expected:**

```
[Ian, Kowalsky, 2000, Pit, Johnson, 2001, Adam, Todd, 1999]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create a new list in which the elements are the words from the previous list of phrases, you could do:

```
list.stream()                           // [Ian Kowalsky 2000, Pit Johnson 2001, Adam Todd 1999]
   .map(phrase -> phrase.split("\\s+")) // [[Ian, Kowalsky, 2000], [Pit, Johnson, 2001], [Adam, Todd, 1999]]
   .flatMap(Arrays::stream)             // [Ian, Kowalsky, 2000, Pit, Johnson, 2001, Adam, Todd, 1999]
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Check the documentation for `flatMap` in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
List<String> result = lines.stream()
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split every line into words, and can use java8+, try this :

Load the lines via `Files.lines` and then simply use `String.split`to explode your lines into words... Something like so :

```java
List<String> words = Files.lines(file).flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class WordsOfFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> words = Files.lines(new File("X.txt").toPath()).flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        words.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

HTH!